# What's the word for the property of being divisible by a particular number?

Tags: word-choice, terminology, mathematics

Example:

> Since x is even (i.e., divisible by 2), its *--word--* is true.
>   Since y is odd, y's *--word--* is false.

The description suggests 'moddity', but there was another word for it...

<sub>BTW, I don't know if I should've asked this on [Math](https://math.stackexchange.com/) on [SE](http://stackexchange.com), so sorry if this violates this site's FAQ (my first question here).</sub>

Comment: I don't understand the question. Do you mean only divisible by 2? The title doesn't say this.

Comment: @Urbycoz Edited the title. w/o adding anything else, it is assumed to be for two, but it can be used for any number...

Comment: The property of being divisible by X is called [divisibility by X](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_rule).

Comment: @RegDwightАΑA No, there was another "boolean" word, i.e., it could be true or false

Comment: Divisibility by X is boolean. It is or isn't divisible by X

Comment: @XavierVidalHernández I realize that. Should I delete it and just forget about the word? (it's been nagging me for a couple of days; I hope you know the feeling, a memory in the back of your mind that you can't resurface for long enough to actually get what it was...)

Comment: @YatharthROCK: There's a [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/49303) here that talks about that...

Comment: The word is "even".  If x(even) = "true" then x is divisible by 2.  (don't know how to do subscripts, use your imagination)

Comment: It doesn't make sense unless the term includes the divisor (e.g. 2) as every number is divisible by itself and 1.  Unless you mean prime/non-prime

Comment: I down voted as this question doesn't belong here as it's about specialised mathematics terminology (I believe the answer would involve using the term 'modulo' but I'm not sure how to phrase it).

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Yes, 'modulo' is the root for 'moddity'. Also, I was afraid I'd be down-voted there too for not really talking about 'concepts'/'algorithms'/'specific problems'/etc...

Comment: @Bob Use `<sub><sub>`

Comment: @JasperLoy See my other comment

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I don't believe that it's an exact fit, you can consider the word, [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_%28mathematics%29):

> In mathematics, the *parity* of an object states whether it is even or odd.

Wiktionary also [provides an example](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parity):

> (mathematics, countable) A set with the property of having all of its elements belonging to one of two disjoint subsets, especially a set of integers split in subsets of even and odd elements.
>
> ***Parity** is always preserved in such operations.*

Comment: _<astonishment>_ Why, yes, I was thinking of parity!

Comment: Thanks, it feels good to finally be able to scratch that itch (was that correct usage BTW?) :)

Comment: @YatharthROCK You're welcome and yes, your usage is fine.

Comment: @JasperLoy Well, my memory _was_ quite fuzzy...

Comment: See https://plus.google.com/115093555862694271963/posts/X88UHRPzLjF